# What is the most general setting in which the inverse image functor has a left adjoint?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, adjoint-functors, closed-map

Let $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes. We have that the functors 
$$ f^{-1}: \text{Sh}(Y) \longrightarrow \text{Sh}(X)  $$
and 
$$ f_{*}: \text{Sh}(X) \longrightarrow \text{Sh}(Y)  $$
are an adjoint pair $ f^{-1} \dashv f_{*}$. In the case that $f$ is an open immersion, we further have an adjunction
$$ f_{!} \dashv f^{-1} \dashv f_{*}  $$
where $f_{!}$ is determined by extending by zero. Similarly, $f$ is a closed immersion, we have an adjunction
$$  f^{-1} \dashv f_{*} \dashv f^{!}   $$

Now it is my understanding at least (correct me if I am wrong), that we also have this right adjoint in the case that $f$ is proper, which generalizes the case of $f$ being a closed immersion. I was wondering if there is a similar generalization for the left adjoint of $f^{-1}$. Is there some way of generalizing "open immersion" in the same way that proper generalizes "closed immersion"?

If not, can it be done if we relax ourselves to presheaves? What about if we relax ourselves to locally ringed spaces or just ringed spaces?

Comment: This is not true that for a proper morphism $f$, the functor $f_*$ has a right adjoint. In fact, if $f:X\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}k$ is the structural morphism, then $f_*$ is the same has the global section functor, and this may not be exact.

But just to be sure, what do you mean by $\operatorname{Sh}(X)$ ? Is it the category of all the sheaves, or all the $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules or only the quasi-coherent ones ? Your last sentence made me wonder. Depending on the category, the answer might not be the same.

Comment: If you mean sheaves (then $X$ needs not be a scheme, just a topological space), then the functor $f^{-1}$ has a left adjoint if $f$ is a local homeomorphism (generalizing the case $f$ open immersion). If you take presheaves, then the functor $f_*$ always has a right adjoint.